# Activiti kickstart deploy on alfresco 5 with CMIS

Tags: java, alfresco, activiti, cmis, apache-chemistry

I have installed Alfresco 5.0d and want to use the Activiti Designer 5.18 with Eclipse Kepler. When I try to deploy an Activiti process using the CMIS-API, I get the following exception:

`org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.exceptions.CmisRuntimeException: null
at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.AbstractAtomPubService.convertStatusCode(AbstractAtomPubService.java:487)
at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.AbstractAtomPubService.post(AbstractAtomPubService.java:629)
at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.ObjectServiceImpl.createDocument(ObjectServiceImpl.java:119)
at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.SessionImpl.createDocument(SessionImpl.java:751)
at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.FolderImpl.createDocument(FolderImpl.java:95)
at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.FolderImpl.createDocument(FolderImpl.java:469)
at org.activiti.designer.kickstart.eclipse.navigator.CmisUtil.uploadProcess(CmisUtil.java:214)
at org.activiti.designer.kickstart.eclipse.ui.wizard.diagram.ExportKickstartProcessWizard.exportProcess(ExportKickstartProcessWizard.java:189)
at org.activiti.designer.kickstart.eclipse.ui.wizard.diagram.ExportKickstartProcessWizard$1.run(ExportKickstartProcessWizard.java:88)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:122)`

My Activiti Kickstart configuration within eclipse is the following:

**CMIS URL**: http://ip-to-alfresco:8081/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.0/atom

**CMIS Workflow Definitions Path**: /Datenverzeichnis/Workflow-Definitionen
(because of a german installation. This folder exists)

**CMIS Models path**: /Datenverzeichnis/Modelle

**CMIS Share config Path**: /Sites/surf-config

**Share reload webscript url**: http://ip-to-alfresco:8081/share/service/reload-module-deployments

**Custom repo tomcat folder**: .../shared/classes/alfresco/extension

**Custom share tomcat folder**: .../shared/classes/alfresco/web-extension

Therefore, I ask myself if the Activiti Designer Kickstart Plug-in is compatible with Akfresco 5.0d?

Thanks and best regards
Ben

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure if it's compatible (I haven't tried it yet), but you'd definitely change the url to the **1.1** version of CMIS instead of the 1.0.

Let me know if that helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already tried the CMIS 1.1 endpoint without success.